# Search data from 2 or more collection using search keyword in mongodb with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am getting data from 2 collections using keyword search in the child collection from mongodb. I am using aggregate function to set the lookup and search from the lookup. I tried inside the pipeline with $regexMatch. But it is not working with $and condition. here is my code,

```
"$lookup": {
                            "from": "post_cloths",
                            let: { postId: '$_id', search: 'abc' },
                            pipeline: [
                                {
                                    $match: {
                                        $expr:
                                        {
                                            $regexMatch: {
                                                input: "$category",
                                                regex: /c/,
                                                options: "i"
                                            },
                                            $and:
                                                [
                                                    { $eq: ["$postId", "$$postId"] },
                                                    // { $search: ["$cateogry", 'abc'] }
                                                ],
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "as": "postCloth"
                        }
```

without $and it working fine..

The problem statement is -- I have 2 collections one is posts and another is postCloths. I need to return data from post collection along with lookup with postCloth with some search keword.

lookup will return the collection if any of the key is matched on that collection, like just a formal search from the database.

I am getting the data from the $and statement, but need to search all the keys along with the above $eq statement

Here the output I required-----

all data from the post collection which contains the keyword in postCloth. So I need multiple like (in terms of sql) statement in lookup statement. I mean search on multiple keys

Thanks in advance

Comment: $regexMatch should be within $and: `{$and: [{$eq:[...]}, {$regexMatch:{...}}]}`. As a side note, "it is not working" is not a problem statement. Try to be more precise - what you expect and what you get instead. The "not working" is too vague as it can be anything from a critical error to unexpected data format.

Comment: Sorry @AlexBlex I have update some more explanation. Hope you are able to understand my problem statement.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have put the regexMatch inside the $and, how can I match the same regex for multiple keys on that collection?

Comment: what stops you using multiple regexMatch, one per field?

Comment: Got it now. Thanks.